# Flash Packager for IOS: Is the performance for the compiled app too poor to use?

Tags: flash, ios

I am looking to develop a ipad app that relies on a lot of animation - mainly cutout animation and was looking at using flash CS 5 to publish a flash app to ios.

I see a few articles on poor performance for flash apps on ios. Anyone have any experience in using flash to publish for ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing some testing with it and the frame rate was horrible.  It ended up being easier to start learning Objective-c than to use the Packager for iOS.  That being said I saw this link the other day (http://forums.adobe.com/thread/826112) talking about Air 2.6 for iOS.  Worth reading.  I haven't messed with it yet but I did do a quick test with an Air app running on the Motorola Xoom with Android and it worked great so maybe there's some hope.

Comment: Apologies for the late response - went and learned objective c and cocos2d.